# Can I get the original size of an image in Next.js 13(next/image)

Tags: image, next.js13

I'd like to get the original size of an image in Next.js 13(next/image).
I've tried various methods, but couldn't get the correct values.
The returned size is approximately 39% downsized in Next.js 13.
I've tested it on various browsers like Chrome and Safari, and even with multiple images, it doesn't work.
However, if I use vanilla JS or just use  without using next/image, it works correctly. The issue seems to be related to Next.js 13.
Can you provide any insights into the methods or reasons behind this discrepancy?

```
import Image from 'next/image'

...

const refTest = useRef(null)

// try1
useEffect(() => {
        if (refTest) {
            console.log(refTest.current.naturalWidth)
        }
    }, [refTest])

// try2
const handleImageLoad = () => {
        if (refTest.current) {
            console.log(refTest.current.naturalWidth)
        }
    }
...

<Image ref={refTest} src="/images/test.jpg" alt="test image" fill onLoad={handleImageLoad} />


// result: about 39% * original size
```

But it is working

```
const refTest = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
        if (refTest) {
            console.log(refTest.current.naturalWidth)
        }
    }, [refTest])

<img ref={refTest} src="/images/test.jpg" />

// result: original size
```

Comment: Can you please describe the purpose of console image width? May can suggest alternate way.

Comment: @maulik Perhaps there is an alternative. I think we can use js and <img/> as an alternative. However, I asked you because I wanted to use next fully since I am configuring the service with next. The reason for the need for this feature is to create a service such as a web image editor, and to produce different results depending on the difference between the original size of the image and the size of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion with your actual code** :

```
unoptimized = {false} // {false} | {true}
```

When true, the source image will be served as-is instead of changing quality, size, or format. Defaults to false.

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#unoptimized

Also can use "devicesizes" with next.config.js for screen vise adaptation.
Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#devicesizes

---

However, As per the given comment regarding your need, I hope any one of the two possible options can fit your needs.

**Option 1:**
to display a different image for mobile and desktop, sometimes called Art Direction, you can provide different src, width, height, and quality props to getImageProps(). In your case , can use same image with diff height and width.

```
import { getImageProps } from 'next/image'
 
export default function Home() {
  const common = { alt: 'Art Direction Example', sizes: '100vw' }
  const {
    props: { srcSet: desktop },
  } = getImageProps({
    ...common,
    width: 1440,
    height: 875,
    quality: 80,
    src: '/images/test.jpg', /* Desktop */
  })
  const {
    props: { srcSet: mobile, ...rest },
  } = getImageProps({
    ...common,
    width: 750,
    height: 1334,
    quality: 70,
    src: '/images/test.jpg', /* mobile */
  })
 
  return (
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcSet={desktop} />
      <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcSet={mobile} />
      <img {...rest} style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
    </picture>
  )
}
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#art-direction

**Option 2:**

```
<Image
  fill
  src="/images/test.jpg"
  sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
/>
```

The value of sizes will greatly affect performance for images using fill or which are styled to have a responsive size.
Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are attempting to use refTest.current.naturalWidth to get the natural width of the image. However, this approach might not work as expected with the next/image component.

Instead, you can use the onLoad event to get the natural width and height of the image after it has loaded. Here's an example:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

const ImageComponent = () => {
  const refTest = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleLoad = () => {
      console.log(refTest.current.naturalWidth);
    };

    if (refTest.current) {
      refTest.current.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);
    }

    return () => {
      if (refTest.current) {
        refTest.current.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
      }
    };
  }, [refTest]);

  return (
    <Image
      ref={refTest}
      src="/images/test.jpg"
      alt="test image"
      fill
      onLoad={() => console.log('Image loaded')}
    />
  );
};

export default ImageComponent;
```

Comment: I tried using the code you mentioned, but it's not working properly. I modified some of the original text. Please refer to it. And I found something new in your code. addEventListener/load is not working. "handleLoad()" is not working.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.